# How to support different language versions in my lexer/parser

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I am wondering what is the best way to support different versions of a language in my grammar.

I am working on modifying an existing grammar for a language and there is a new version of the language, introducing new keywords and additional syntax I should be able to parse. However, existing codebase written in the language can already use these new keywords as identifiers for example, so I have to make this extension optional.

So my question is: what is the preferred way to write conditional lexer and parser rules, based on a boolean value? Semantic predicates came to my mind, but I am relatively new to antlr and I'm not sure if it is a good idea to use them for such a purpose.

Comment: You probably should ship two pairs of lexers/parsers in that case and add command line switch (like `--language-version v1`) to your console application so that at runtime it can use the proper lexer/parser to enforce the language version chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had very good success with semantic predicates in the [MySQL grammar](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/library/parsers/grammars/MySQLParser.g4), to support various MySQL versions. This includes new features, removed features and features that were valid only for a certain MySQL version range. Additionally, you can use the semantic predicates to tell the user in which version a specific syntax would be valid. But you have to parse the predicates yourself for that.

As an example, in [this line](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/library/parsers/grammars/MySQLParser.g4#L97) a new import statement is conditionally added:

```sql
simpleStatement:
    // DDL
    ...
    | {serverVersion >= 80000}? importStatement
```

I have a field `serverVersion` in my [common recognizer class](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/library/parsers/mysql/MySQLRecognizerCommon.h#L61) from which both generated lexer and parser classes derive. This field is set with a valid version, right before the parsing process is triggered.

Also in the lexer you can guard keywords with this approach, like shown in [this and surrounding lines](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/library/parsers/grammars/MySQLLexer.g4#L591) in the MySQL lexer:

```sql
MASTER_SYMBOL:                   M A S T E R;
MASTER_TLS_VERSION_SYMBOL:       M A S T E R '_' T L S '_' V E R S I O N     {serverVersion >= 50713}?;
MASTER_USER_SYMBOL:              M A S T E R '_' U S E R;
MASTER_HEARTBEAT_PERIOD_SYMBOL:  M A S T E R '_' H E A R T B E A T '_' P E R I O D?;
MATCH_SYMBOL:                    M A T C H;                                  // SQL-2003-R
MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR_SYMBOL: M A X '_' C O N N E C T I O N S '_' P E R '_' H O U R;
MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR_SYMBOL:     M A X '_' Q U E R I E S '_' P E R '_' H O U R;
MAX_ROWS_SYMBOL:                 M A X '_' R O W S;
MAX_SIZE_SYMBOL:                 M A X '_' S I Z E;
MAX_STATEMENT_TIME_SYMBOL:
    M A X '_' S T A T E M E N T '_' T I M E                                  {50704 < serverVersion && serverVersion < 50708}?
;
MAX_SYMBOL:                      M A X                                       { setType(determineFunction(MAX_SYMBOL)); }; // SQL-2003-N
MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR_SYMBOL:     M A X '_' U P D A T E S '_' P E R '_' H O U R;
MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS_SYMBOL:     M A X '_' U S E R '_' C O N N E C T I O N S;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches you can take:

1. If the additional syntax is not valid with the earlier version of the grammar and the interpretation of the previously valid expressions are not changing - only then you can consider using something like semantic predicates to be able to gauge which part of input is parsed with the new grammar and which one with the old one.

Example being: extending integer calculator to support floats

`1.0` is invalid with the earlier grammar and new grammar does not change semantics of `1` (integer) calculations.
This condition is not so easy to be met as it may seem - there might be quite nuanced conditions particularly if the grammar or its new versions are complex.

2. Have two versions of the lexer/parser and switch them on independently as @lex-li suggests. This is the safe path that does not have to deal with the semantic changes of the old expressions with the additions of the new grammar syntax.